# Does a kafka consumer directly talk to zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I would like to know if a kafka consumer/producer version 3.2 (not in kraft mode) is directly reading/connecting from/to zookeeper or not ?

I think so and I found answers about this but I can't find this information clearly written in the official documentation.
Maybe I'm wrong.

Is some one can spot me a kafka official documentation about this ?

Thanks

I'm reading the documentation, but I can't find it.

Comment: "Think so" based on what? Did you run a tcpdump and check the network traffic, for example?

Answer (score 2):

Only the brokers are connected to Zookeeper (when not in Kraft mode). Clients (applications) only know the brokers (`bootstrap.servers`) and only need connectivity to access the brokers.

In older versions (< 0.9 I believe), the clients were connected to Zookeeper to commit their offsets and get metadata. It became optional later on, in favor of a unique connection to the brokers instead.